# In react router 4, how does one negate a route / path using regex?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

Say i have a route switch statement like the following:

```
render () {
    <pre>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/foo" render={render}>
            <Route path="/bar" render={renderBar}>
            <Route path="/" render={renderHome}>

            {/* How do i express everything except the home page ?*/}

            <Route render={renderFourOhFour}>
        </Switch>
    </pre>
}
```

How do i write a route that excludes everything except the home page given the above example? Do i just write a regex? If so i've tried something like

`path={^(?!.*(home))}`

with the regex react router v4 tester: https://pshrmn.github.io/route-tester/#/

Comment: Is this ` <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>` not what you're looking for?

Comment: Hmm I want everything except home; so no. That's not what i'm looking for. There something i should clarify to help you understand?

Comment: @chrisjlee Can you kindly clarifying the following: " How do i express everything except the home page"

Do you want a specific route which will take you to the homepage? Can you describe what your objectives are in a nontechnical way?

Comment: Oh ok. I see. So how do i negate '/' in a regex?

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP is asking "How do I match on everything *except* a particular route". Something like `<Route path="/" not="home">` I have the same question.

Comment: The package used in React Router is path-to-regex. I don't see anything in the docs that lets you write a path that excludes certain paths.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `render` method on the Route, which gets passed the location as a prop. So:

```
<Route render={({location}) => {
  return location.pathname !== '/' ? <p>Not home</p> : ''
}} />
```

Answer (score 1):

1) It will be visible everywhere except `/home`

```
<Route path={/\/(?!home)/} component={Component} />
```

2) Everywhere except `/`

```
<Route path={/^.{2,}$/} component={Component} />
```

Answer (score 0):

In react router 4, there isn't a explicit way to.  I had redesign it in a way that the switch statement as a stack or queue.

It'll match the first few route components as the first choices and you'll have to place the last item as the default.

**For example:**

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
<Route path="/will-match" component={WillMatch}/>
<Route component={NoMatch} />
```